# Opened a solution on a different computer and now it isn't working ("base class 'System.Void' cannot be designed")

Tags: vb.net

I opened a vb solution on a different computer from the one I created it on. Now when I try to open a form in the designer, it gives me this error: "The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: frmSearchSort --- The base class 'System.Void' cannot be designed."

When I looked at the code for all my forms, 'System.Void' isn't there. I'm not exactly sure what any of this means. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this happening for all forms? If you look at the user and designer code files for an affected form, is there a base class specified in either? Is there any other class declared in the same code file?

Comment: When you say you opened a solution, did you copy all the files to the second computer? Is the directory structure for the solution identical to the first computer. Are you using the same version of Visual Studio on the second computer?